# How can i modify this sql for execute?

Tags: mysql, sql

create table wallet(userId int , coin int, primary key(userId));

update wallet SET coin=coin-(least(select coin FROM wallet where userId=101,500)) where userId=101;

Comment: what do you want to do ? just run it?

Comment: I don't think that's the kind of question someone working with "wallets" and "coins" should be asking.

Comment: This sql have syntax error but i couldn't figure it out.

Comment: the syntax error is `,500` should be after the parenthesis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one

```
update wallet 
SET coin=coin-(least(coin,500)) 
where userId=101;
```

or the other maybe

```
update wallet 
SET coin=case when coin < 500 then 0 else coin-500 end
where userId=101;
```